# Write a load of strings from a MySQL DB to a input area in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, input

Hi so i was wondering how do i get a load of string from a mysql database and put them in a input area with a return between each value such as

> Hi
>   My
>   Name
>   Is
>   Joris

Thanks,
Joris

Comment: More information needed. What the table looks like and the data in it?

Comment: Dear @Jonis. You need to learn how to talk to people. Your "its simple names" says NOTHING! What form it's stored in? what is table structure? what is data example? It should be your damn concern - how to provide maximum information regarding your question, not someone's else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating a `<textarea>` in a form, the text between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags is the default text for the text area.  You just need to build a pair of these with the string you want between them, like this:  `<textarea>$string</textarea>`.  Do the query and the concatenating in PHP using `\n` for newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a carriage return after each string and then output this within the required textarea.

For example:

```
<?php
    $cr = "\n";
    $bigString = 'Hello' . $cr . 'there.';

    echo '<textarea>' . $bigString . '</textarea>';
?>
```